# How to create blackberry ui like homescreen

Tags: blackberry

Please i would like help to create a screen like these:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOBcP.jpg],

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd9h5.jpg]

Im particularly interested in the sliding area..i mean where you have the title, then you can scroll left or right for another title/section

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at PaneView for OS 6.0 and above.  Tutorial here: http://dftr.ca/?p=190

Comment: @PeterStrange: I will check and get back, thanks

Comment: PeterStrange - thanks that was exactly what i was looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments above. the answer would appear to be PaneView for OS 6.0 and above:

Tutorial here: [dftr.ca/?p=190](http://dftr.ca/?p=190)

OS 6.0 documentation here: [PaneView](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/pane/PaneView.html)